# How to replace dictionary values found in text with dictionary keys using Python and docx?

Tags: python, regex, python-docx

I am currently trying to reformat a document using docx by replacing dictionary values found in the text with their corresponding keys. A direct swap from values to keys won't work because the first instance has to be value (key). Additionally, any other instances where value (key) occurs later in the text should be transformed to just the key. Example below:

Dictionary: {km: Kilometer}

'The Kilometer (km) %   is very powerful. Blah blah  blah blah. The Kilometer this. The Kilometer (km) that km.', 'the Kilometer is called km'

to this:

'The Kilometer (km) %   is very powerful. Blah blah  blah blah. The km this. The km that km.', 'the km is km called km'

I've tried the below without success.

```py
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:

    for key, value in acronyms.items():

        # Replace the value with the key in the paragraph text

        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(value, key)
```

As well as trying this without success:

```py
from docx import Document
import re

# Define your acronym dictionary
acronyms = {
    'km': 'kilometer',
    # Add more acronyms as needed
}

print(acronyms[keys])
# Open the Word document
doc = Document("acronymnsTest.docx")

# Extract text from the document
document_text = ""

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    document_text += paragraph.text + " "

# Split the document text into words
document_words = document_text.split()
document_words = ' '.join(document_words)

# Create a dictionary for first_used
first_used = {key: False for key in acronyms}

list1 = [document_words]
list2 = []

for qey, valves in acronyms.items():
    #print(valves)
    for inputText in list1:
        for key in first_used:
            if first_used[key] is False:
                replacement = "$%^#$$"
                if  valves + '(' + key + ')' in inputText:
                    inputText = re.sub(r'\b' + re.escape(valves) + r'(?=\s|%|\b)', replacement, inputText, count=1)
                    inputText = inputText.replace(' ' + valves + ' ', ' ' + key + ' ')
                    inputText = inputText.replace(' ' + valves + '.', ' ' + key + '.')
                    first_used[key] = True
                    print(inputText)
                    inputText = inputText.replace(replacement, valves)
                    list2.append(inputText)
                elif valves + ' ' + key + ' ' in inputText:
                    replacement = "$%^#$$"
                    inputText = re.sub(r'\b' + re.escape(valves + ' ' + key) + r'(?=\s|%|\b)', replacement, inputText, count=1)
                    inputText = inputText.replace(' ' + valves + ' ', ' ' + key + ' ')
                    inputText = inputText.replace(' ' + valves + '.', ' ' + key + '.')
                    inputText = inputText.replace(replacement, valves + ' (' + key + ')')
                    first_used[key] = True
                    list2.append(inputText)
                elif ' ' + key + ' ' in inputText:
                    replacement = "$%^#$$"
                    inputText = re.sub(r'\b' + re.escape(key) + r'\b', replacement, inputText, count=1)
                    inputText = inputText.replace(' ' + valves + ' ', ' ' + key + ' ')
                    inputText = inputText.replace(' ' + valves + '.', ' ' + key + '.')
                    inputText = inputText.replace(replacement, valves + ' (' + key + ')')
                    first_used[key] = True
                    list2.append(inputText)
                else:
                    pass
                    print("nope")
            else:
                inputText = inputText.replace(' ' + acronyms[key] + ' ', ' ' + key + ' ')
                list2.append(inputText)

# Print or use the modified text
for modified_text in list2:
    print(modified_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be interesting to create a subclass of `dict` that only returned values after the first key hit had been done so I tried this.

```py
class skip_first_dict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.found_items = set()
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        key_lower = key.lower()
        if key_lower in super().keys() and key_lower not in self.found_items:
            self.found_items.add(key_lower)
            return key
        return super().get(key_lower, default)
```

You might use it like:

```py
text = """
The Kilometer (km) % is very powerful.
Blah blahb blah blah.
The Kilometer this.
The Kilometer (km) that km.', 'the Kilometer is called km
"""

lookup = skip_first_dict({
    "kilometer" : "km"
})

print("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
print(text)
print("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
print("".join(lookup.get(x, x) for x in re.split(r"(\b)", text)))
print("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

That should give you:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx

The Kilometer (km) % is very powerful.
Blah blahb blah blah.
The Kilometer this.
The Kilometer (km) that km.', 'the Kilometer is called km

xxxxxxxxxxxx

The Kilometer (km) % is very powerful.
Blah blahb blah blah.
The km this.
The km (km) that km.', 'the km is called km

xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Of course to be complete you would probably want to do something similar with `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, `list1 = [document_words]` implies `list1` is a list of individual words.

I think you're also saying you'd like the first occurrence to remain as is, but sub all remaining occurrences.

You can parse `list1`, and replace all (except the first) matched words with the acronym by doing the following.

```py
# Change first_used to use value, instead of key.
first_used = {value: False for value in acronyms.values()}

for inputText in list1:
    # Word has an abbreviation sub
    if inputText in first_used:
        # Word has been seen before, sub it
        if first_used[inputText] is True:
            # Do your replacements accordingly <ADD CODE>.
        # First time seeing word with abbreviation, record it
        else:
            # Note down first occurrence has been met <ADD CODE>.
            first_used[inputText] = True
    # Word has no abbreviation sub
    else:
        # Nothing to sub <ADD CODE>.
```

Hopefully I got your requirements right.